# Rails 3 Contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently followed a tutorial on a how to add a contact form in rails 3 for a site I am building. I already had a contact controller and view from when I created that page and was trying to implement the form. I coming to realize maybe the tutorial isn't in rails 3 when it says it is. I keep getting an error( undefined method `deliver_contact' for Notifications:Class. ) that I can't seem to figure out. I tried changing some thing around from the tutorial but nothing is working. Any guidance would help me out? I am thinking about just deleting what I did and starting over fresh with the contact form but wanted to check and see if anybody has an idea. Thanks! The link to the site is below and I followed exactly what was there.

http://metatroid.com/article/How%20To:%20Contact%20Form%20in%20Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```rails
Notifications.contact(params[:email]).deliver
```

[More info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: undefined method `subject' for #<Notifications:0x007f83c011b868>

Rails.root: /home/whitey7/hire2fixit
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/mailers/notifications.rb:4:in `contact'
app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:8:in `send_mail'

Comment: read the guide I linked and use example from it(welcome_email), your article is not for 3rd rails

Comment: mail(:from => email_params[:address], :to => "your_email@example.com", :subject => email_params[:subject]), message to view etc

Comment: Thanks I will see what I can find out.